# join table creating unintentional NULL entries in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I got the following models. The join table references the user_id and the course_id and the combination is set unique. However, after testing my page on the server, e.g. leaving and joining courses many times,also with another current_user my join table created records where the course_id was empty. This got me errors in fetching data afterwards. So now I tried adding `:false => null`. Could this help? thx for your time

```
def self.up
  create_table :course_enrollments do |t|
  t.references :user, :null => false
  t.references :course, :null => false
  t.timestamps
end
  add_index :course_enrollments, [:user_id, :course_id], :unique => true
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code that joins and leaves the course?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `:null => false` will cause an exception when you try to save a `CourseEnrollment` with a null ID. That's fine if you write the controller action to handle the exception. You could (and should) add `validates_presence_of :user_id, :course_id` in the CourseEnrollment model, so that instances with null IDs will not be valid, and can be handled with the normal `<model>.save` method.

However the bigger question is why does your app save rows with null IDs in the first place? For example, you might be creating orphaned rows (by deleting the associated Course or User). Generally it's a good idea to add `:dependent => :destroy` on `has_many` associations to prevent this.